# Wordpress super admin login issue. (Automatically logout)

Tags: php, wordpress, multisite

I have created super admin and after login the super admin in admin panel it's not allowed to access other pages like(plugins & users).

It's automatically logout again redirect to admin login page.

Please anyone let me know . Whats is the reason this type of issue accrue.

I have deactivate all plugins & themes and checked the issue still raised.

Please don't marked the question duplicate of [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10967621/wordpress-mu-cant-access-wp-admin)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue reason is primary key and auto increment value may be not set.

So Please check the this User & session related table column primary key & auto increment value.

That is the reason session details not stored in database. sometime multiple users also not able to login in same time at different browser.

Comment: Thank you so much. My issue has already fixed. this suggestion is right. Once after change my wp-user & wp-usermeta table primary ID's it's working fine. Thanks.